# Manga/manhwa about a female lead who is reincarnated/reborn as a magician, then exiled to a snowy territory

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, reincarnation

I lost my phone and got a new one, but lost some of the manga/manhwa that I saved; please help.

So first one: I think a a kid (female lead) was reincarnated/reborn and she is a magician. Then she was, I think, exiled, then proceeded to go to this winter/snowy territory, where she convinced a silver-haired guy (the villain, or related to it) that she can be useful fighting the demons, like beyond the walls. After few years pass of her becoming useful, she met the supposed black hair (male lead) as a child, being a slave, then saved him.

The story was in full color, and that's really all I can remember.

Comment: What colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: its silver shes a child and a magician something about ice

Comment: Okay, thanks, we'll try and find this for you. If anyone posts a correct answer, you can mark it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manhwa about a girl who is reincarnated into a novel and sent by her family to battle monsters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/281453/manhwa-about-a-girl-who-is-reincarnated-into-a-novel-and-sent-by-her-family-to-b)

Answer (score 5):

This is *[Author of My Own Destiny](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/author-of-my-own-destiny)*, aka *I Became the Wife of the Male Lead*.

> Evil mage Fiona Green was destined to die at the hands of the protagonist couple in “The Emperor and the Saint.” That is, until the story’s author became Fiona herself! Though mistreated, **cast out by her pompous family and thrown into the battle at Heylon, Fiona is determined to use her magic for good**. But things take a rather unexpected turn when **she rescues the male lead**, Siegren, turning him from foe to friend… Will she successfully rewrite her fate without changing the story’s happy ending?

[image: Cover]

The synopsis is a solid match for the description, and the cover image includes the two leads (black haired male lead, silver haired female lead).

Comment: oh my gawd just saw this thank you soo muchhhh