# Manhwa about a girl who is reincarnated into a novel and sent by her family to battle monsters

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

The main character is is reincarnated into her own fantasy novel as the villain.

She has white hair and her family has sent her off to serve mandatory military/draft service in place of her brother. She is only a child but her family sent her off to battle against vicious monsters.

She becomes a powerful mage after proving how well she can serve in battle. The duke/military general wants to adopt her and the male lead falls in love with her.

Does anybody know this manhwa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ***[Author of My Own Destiny](https://myanimelist.net/manga/147661/Author_of_My_Own_Destiny)***...?

> Evil mage Fiona Green was destined to die at the hands of the protagonist couple in The Emperor and the Saint. That is, until the story's author became Fiona herself! Though mistreated, cast out by her pompous family and thrown into the battle at Heylon, Fiona is determined to use her magic for good. But things take a rather unexpected turn when she rescues the male lead, Siegren, turning him from foe to friend... Will she successfully rewrite her fate without changing the story's happy ending?
>
> [image: Promotional art for "Author of My Own Destiny."]

An author is reincarnated as Fiona Green, the white-haired, 13-year-old, illegitimate daughter of a count in the world of a novel she wrote. In the original story, her character is fated to die as the villain, but she's been reincarnated six years before the point where the novel began.

The Count's children all have magical powers and the royal family has ordered him to send one of them to Duke Abel Heilon's castle on the Northern Front to help fight a war against monsters. The Count asks his children if any of them are willing to volunteer, and she ends up being pressured by her elder siblings to do so, as none of them like her or want to go.

When she arrives at the Northern Front, Duke Heilon is sceptical as to whether such a small child will be of any use, thinking that the Count has shortchanged him. He tells her to go home, but she asks for a chance to prove herself in battle, and when he gives her that chance, she demonstrates that her magic is very effective against the monsters, at which point he immediately warms up to her.

Soon after, she saves the male lead of the novel, Siegren, who was wounded on the battlefield, and has him brought back to the Duke's castle to recover.

They both end up remaining at the Duke's castle for the next five years, by which time Siegren has fallen in love with Fiona. In chapter 17, the Duke also offers to adopt her.

You can read the full manhwa at [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/author-of-my-own-destiny/info).

Comment: Yes this is it! Thank you so much! I really appreciate the help.